# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION awaiting Task.sleep

Tags: swift, swiftui

Trying to use the following ObservableObject backed by an actor and getting an error when awaiting Task.sleep

`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Any ideas?

```swift
class Reader: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Reader(actor: .init())

    let actor: TestActor
    @Published var val = 0

    @MainActor func read() async {
        val = await actor.val
    }

    func increment() async -> Bool {
        await actor.increment()
        await read()
        return true
    }

    init(actor: TestActor) {
        self.actor = actor
    }
}

actor TestActor {

    var val = 0

    func increment() async {
        let oldval = val
        await Task.sleep(2000000000) // Error here!
        val += 1
    }

}
```

Comment: What's this?  actor TestActor {}

Comment: @ElTomato just an actor with a single property and method to experiment with actor isolation. `actor` from Swift 5.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Task.sleep crashes with anything but tiny values. This stuff is very new; you are looking at a beta, almost an alpha. It's full of bugs. This is one.

Comment: Thank you! I pulled the value straight from the docs so I expected it to work correctly, but sure enough if I make it significantly smaller, it works.

Comment: I filed a bug report and the Apple folks said they didn't know about this issue, which surprised me. Proving once again it's always worth filing.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed in Xcode Version 13.0 beta 4.